# Lego Batman Figures In Picture Unknown? Please Help

Tags: minifigures, lego-group, minifigure-identification

I missed this purchase by seconds; I was devastated and so was my son; probably me more so. Secretly I am a massive fan.

There are some unusual Batman figures that I haven't seen before. I was wondering if someone is able to identify these so I can search again. Chances of the same bunch coming up are very unlikely. Will buy them individually if that's what it takes.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First off let me apologize for fueling your future addiction to Batman LEGO minifigures.

Bricklink finds me 211 minifigures searching for "batman"

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=batman#T=M

Many of these are related characters and not Batman himself, but there are a lot of Batman minifigures, including some really odd ones:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can also confirm that some of the ones shown in your picture are not Batman and are assembled incorrectly, the middle far right figure appears to be a Nightwing body with a different head and an added cape and batman cowl (original Nightwing shown below), also upper right is clearly superman wearing a bat cowl, if the picture was better you could tell it was dark blue and not black.

[image]
[image]